# What does "There's got to be more to you" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

from song Violet Indiana-air kissing.

Answer (score 4):

It is short version of [there is more to someone (or something) than meets the eye](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/there%27s-more-to-someone-or-something-than-meets-the-eye)

> A person or situation is more complex or interesting than they appear.

**There's got to be more to you** means there must be qualities or features within them that one doesn't know of.

It can be used both to be sarcastic and motivating, depending on the way it is said.

Examples:
(in a chuckling manner) There's got to be more to you than just drinking and philandering.

(in a concerned, low voice) You can't give up because I know there's more to you than that.

Comment: I would add that if someone says "there's got to be more to you" there is probably an implication of "there does not, on the surface, appear to be very much to you". So depending on context it could be taken to be insulting.

Comment: In the context of the hook:  "there's got to be more you / don't let me see / there's no more to you" there is an expression of longing for more depth, integrity, substance, and probably authentic love from the "you" she's referring to in the song.  In the context is the song's storyline, she seems to be making an account of this person (maybe herself.

Comment: (Oops - hit return instead of shift) cont. maybe she's reflecting on her own experiences and behavior and admonishing herself for being so shallow as to accept betrayal in order to gain approval from people in her life who devalue her.  She wants better and more from the person to whom she's crooning her plea.